# How to configure code-coverage in cypress when application is running in a docker container?

Tags: vue.js, cypress, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

My setup:

I have an application's source under `/client` which runs in a docker and mounts on `/app/client` inside the container and instrumenting it with `babel-plugin-istanbul` which seems to work fine:
[image]

However, when cypress with `code-coverage` plugin generates the coverage, it can't find the source code files, since `/app` exists only in the container:

`/coverage/lcov-report/index.html`:

`Unable to lookup source: /app/client/src/.........`

What I tried:

- copy the contents of `/client` to a directory under `/cypress/app/client` and `/app/client` (just in case :P)
- configure nyc to include the full path to `/app`

````
.nycrc.json:

{
 "include": ["C:/........./cypress/app/**/*.js"]
}```
````